# Same command broadcasts OK from command line, but not in a script

Tags: octave, array-broadcasting

I'm relying on broadcasting in the following element-by-element multiplication of a 2x2x2 matrix by a 1x2 matrix (broadcasting means the smaller matrix is repeated as many times as necessary to match the size of the larger one - see end for more explanation). One command gives a "nonconformant arguments" error when in a script run from the octave command line. But exactly the same command runs fine if typed at the octave command line.

Occasionally, the script doesn't give the error, but I haven't worked out exactly what arrangement the Universe has to be in to avoid the error (see later) -- whatever, running it within a script is as robust as a cheap garden strimmer.

I give a workround below, but I'd like to understand what's behind this error.

Here's my script file `mwe_bcast.m`:

```
# Minimum working example of broadcasting an element-by-element multiplication. 
#  The last line errors when run from octave as a script, 
#  but not when typed at the octave command line.
clear
test = [0,1;2,3];
test(:,:,2) = 3 - test;
test .*= 2;
factors = [1,2;3,4];
test .*= factors(1,:)
```

But here's the error when run as a script:

```
>> mwe_bcast
error: mwe_bcast: .*=: nonconformant arguments (op1 is 2x2x2, op2 is 1x2)
error: called from
    mwe_bcast at line 9 column 6
```

Nonetheless, when I then type the last line at the command line there is no error, and the following output shows that the broadcasting has worked as expected:

```
>> test .*= factors(1,:)
test =

ans(:,:,1) =

    0    4
    4   12

ans(:,:,2) =

   6   8
   2   0
```

Even weirder: I checked whether this is repeatable after restarting octave. It is and it isn't! Sometimes, if I run the script any amount of times straight after starting octave (after just a `cd` to the appropriate directory), it runs without errors. But as soon as I edit the script in any way (just changing a comment, and sometimes even just opening it in the octave editor), then re-run the script, I get the error. But, other times, I get the error the first time I run the script after restarting octave.

Workround: I get no error from the script if I don't use the abbreviated assignment (`.*=`) for this broadcast element-by-element multiplication, i.e. replace the last line with:
`test = test .* factors(1,:);`
However, just as weirdly, note that the earlier use of `.*=` in the script to multiply the same matrix by a scalar always works without an error, even though it also relies on broadcasting.

Explanation of broadcasting: Essentially, the last line multiplies the matrix

```
test(:,:,1) = 0,1
              2,3
test(:,:,2) = 3,2
              1,0
```

element-by-element by `[1,2]` which broadcasts as if it were the matrix:

```
factors(:,:,1) = 1,2
                 1,2
factors(:,:,2) = 1,2
                 1,2
```

System:

```
GNU Octave, version 5.2.0
Ubuntu 20.04 LTE
Linux 5.15
```

Comment: looks like a bug (that I can reproduce on 6.3.0 on Windows)

Comment: is anyone able to reproduce on a current version of Octave?  I cannot reproduce in 7.3.0 or he soon-to-be-released v8.

Comment: I'll search but I suspect this is a known bug that was fixed ahead of v7.  the CLI and scripts had some different interpreter rules to accommodate different command-style calling structures that would cause different code paths to be followed and potential for input mode specific bugs.

Comment: I cannot reproduce this on octave 7.3.0 either. Both work as intended on my system. Also, I note that `test` is a bad name for a variable, as it shadows the builtin function `test`. That's why I usually use "testo" as a variable name instead in such cases, which has the added advantage of adding a bit of italian flair to your variable :p  ... Not sure if this relates to your bug at all though.

Comment: Thank you for the v helpful comments so far. I'm happy with the possibility it's a bug - otherwise I was worrying it was me doing something wrong. I had used `test1` for the variable name initially, but thanks for the tip about avoiding the name `test` altho' it seems to make no difference in this case.
I shall use my workround and stick at octave v5.2.0, just because it's the latest that installs with my Ubuntu's package manager. I avoid manual software upgrades until I have a proven need - a principle to keep myself sane and focused on the task at hand. Thanks again, all.